# What Python packages am I missing?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get my local Windows 10 PC up and running with my Django application. I'm a novice at Python and Django. My app was written by another developer who's been very helpful and has limited availability. I also want to sort it out myself for learning purposes.

I downloaded my code from Bitbucket and loaded all of the packages in the base.txt and development.txt files onto my Windows 10 PC. I keep getting several errors when trying to run the server.

App is using in the following:

- Python 3.61
- Django 1.11.3

base.txt file:

```
boto3==1.4.7
celery==4.1.0
click==6.7
dateutils==0.6.6
Django==1.11.3
django-anymail==0.11.1
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-countries==5.0
django-filter==1.0.4
django-solo==1.1.3
django-storages==1.6.5
djangorestframework==3.6.3
djoser==0.6.0
kombu==4.1.0
mysqlclient==1.3.10
Pillow==4.3.0
python-dotenv==0.6.4
python-magic==0.4.13
pytz==2017.2
redis==2.10.6
uWSGI==2.0.15
xlrd==1.2.0
```

I don't get any errors loading the packages; however, when I run the server I get this screenful of error messages:

```
(venv) C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002A64687E0D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver return check_method()
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__ res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__ res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\ewo\urls.py", line 51, in <module> url(r"^api/", include("apps.accounts.urls", namespace="accounts")),
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\apps\accounts\urls.py", line 5, in <module> from . import views
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\apps\accounts\views.py", line 23, in <module> from .serializers import (
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\apps\accounts\serializers.py", line 6, in <module> from apps.company.serializers import EmployeeSerializer
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\apps\company\serializers.py", line 18, in <module> from apps.common.serializers import YesOrNoField
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\apps\common\serializers.py", line 10, in <module> from .validators import CSVValidator, DocumentValidator
      File "C:\Users\romph\dev\EWO-DEV\backend\apps\common\validators.py", line 6, in <module> import magic
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 209, in <module> libmagic = loader.load_lib()
      File "C:\Users\romph\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.6.1\lib\site-packages\magic\loader.py", line 49, in load_lib raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
```

Comment: Constructive advice: I downvoted for referring to error messages as "vomit" (now edited out). That's not a healthy attitude - errors are your friend. They are not always clear, and perhaps there are sometimes too many of them, but the mindset of snarking at the computer is not conducive to good engineering. In every single case, the computer is right, and it did what it was told to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last line gives a pretty good clue.

Visit https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/

and follow the steps for Windows.

> **Windows**
>
> You'll need DLLs for libmagic. @julian-r maintains a pypi
> package with the DLLs ...

You likely need to

`pip install python-magic-bin`

The requirements may have been specific to another os.

Comment: Thank you, AMG! That did it.

Comment: Good stuff. The `bin` stands for binary and pulls down some precompiled dlls to get it working on Windows. You'll see similar stuff now and again. Postgres for example has a similar `psycopg2-binary` which comes in handy if things won't compile on your system for development (see note on https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/ for warning on use on prod).